# Align a ListView in the middle of the screen (layout-large)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having troubles aligning a listview in the middle of the screen like that:
[image]

I created a tablet layout (layout-large) and I cannot figure out why the layout looks like that:
[image]

This is my list_item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/degree_circle_container">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_heighta="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/bg_temperature"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/temperatureLabel"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/circleImageView"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="100"
            android:textColor="#f25019"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/degree_circle_container"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/degree_circle_container"
        android:src="@mipmap/clear_day"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dayNameLabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iconImageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        tools:text="Wednesday"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

This is the "Daily" layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            tools:context="koemdzhiev.com.stormy.ui.DailyForecastActivity"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_daily_forecast_data"
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This week&apos;s weather"
    android:id="@+id/thisWeekLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/developer_email"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
    android:id="@+id/developer_email"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/daily_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="v 2.0"
    android:id="@+id/appVersion"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Comment: try adding android:gravity ="center" on the listview

Comment: Try centerInParent or some attribute like that;

Comment: In your ListView add   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: please, tell us if any of the solutions worked for you, good luck !

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes the solutions you guys proposed worked but I had to use a combination of them. I did not have internet connection, sorry guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your app looks like the image that you give :

1 - First add `layout_below = "@id/yourViews"` so the listview would be under << YourViews >>

2- Try `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` inside your Listview too

If any trouble leave a comment

Comment: The answer on its own did not fix the problem. I had to use a combination of the answers here. However, I will accept your answer since it pointed me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`
or/and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` at the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You want your content to be aligned in center , then android:gravity="center" should work . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to the `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` because this is the Layout which is nested in the parent `RelativeLayout`.

Also you should add the `layout_below = "@id/yourViews"` as minos23 told you.